# Fatal Error in Swift unwrapping an Optional value using data from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, null, runtime-error

I am trying to display a currently logged in username and I am getting a fatal error about an unexpected nil for an optional value. I've searched several of the other questions related to my issue (using "if let") and attempted the solution but for some reason I cannot get this code to display in my label even though I am ,in fact, showing a value for my variable on debug. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var welcomeText: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if  let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        welcomeText.text = "Welcome  \(currentUser)!"

    } else {

        welcomeText.text = "Welcome"
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }
}
```

I have even tried (as I posted this) moving my code to the viewWillAppear() function to see if that made a difference considering that has helped in the past, but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

error:
[image: as you can see here, I have a value on debug, and the error in the lower right.]

Comment: You can't see the initialization in the screenshot, but if you look at the code that is in the original question i initialize the label as the very first thing I do.

Comment: Have you connected your label in IB to the code? You have to right click and drag to the code to form a connection, not just write @IBOutlet

Comment: No you don't to initialize the variable you need to do welcomeText = UILabel() the only thing you did was to create an outlet (that is not initialized)

Comment: I have dragged and dropped the label to my swift file yes. It's the only way I create outlets.

Comment: No @IcaroNZ you don't need to do that. And are you 100% sure you did it Unconquered82... Sorry but that is what would cause the crash. Also, remember to call super in viewWillAppear:

Comment: I am 100% positive I added it the way you are suggesting. Frankly, It's the only way I do it. For whatever reason it must have lost it's connection in the nib and deleting it and re-adding the outlet solved the issue this time. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills! Thanks for the help! Please answer it Ben so I can give credit where credit is due. This is kind of "buggy" if you ask me.

Comment: Glad to help :) It happens to everyone once in a while. From now on you'll recognize it right away. I undeleted my answer from earlier, which I see you've accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your label that is nil. It looks to me like the connection for the label between Interface Builder and your code got disconnected. You'll need to right click and drag from the label to the outlet property to form the connection again.

Comment: I declared the Outlet this way initially however somehow the outlet needed to be deleted and re-added. Solved the problem. Strange, but solved. Thanks Ben!

Comment: @Unconquered82 nice catch! I was sure that the label wasn't been initialized just did not realize was because it is disconnect, just learn something new! Thanks

Comment: @IcaroNZ Make sure you only use IBOutlet if you're loading the view from a storyboard or nib. From your answer and comments it kind of sounds like you use it with views you create programmatically as well.

Comment: @BenKane, Yes I delete that post I got confuse with the outlets and local variables, so I decide to delete to no confuse anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, put the parse code separate. I guess you try to assign the Parse data before it is ready.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var welcomeText: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
welcomeMessage()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }

    func welcomeMessage () {
    if  let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

            welcomeText.text = "Welcome  \(currentUser)!"

        } else {

            welcomeText.text = "Welcome"
        }
    }

}
```

It still would be very helpful to see more code, where is your code to fetch the user? Did you try to set the label Text there as well? Did that work?